# C program time_t and struct tm, same result?

Tags: c, mktime

I am new to C program and I got a some problem when I code the program using mktime function.

I declare 2 time, first one is system time, and the second one is 1 day before it, here is my code:

```
struct tm *now = calloc(1,sizeof(struct tm));
struct tm *dayb4 = calloc(1,sizeof(struct tm));
time_t t1 = time(NULL);

now = localtime(&t1);
dayb4 = localtime(&t1);

dayb4->tm_day -= 1;
mktime(dayb4);
```

However, I found the the time "now" and "dayb4" are the same, which is 1 day before current time...
Could anyone told me which part I getting wrong?

Thank a lot !!!

Comment: Use `*now = *localtime(&t1);` and `*dayb4 = *localtime(&t1);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arise when you update `localtime()` return value, you need to use `localtime_r()`:

```
struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timep);
```

The return value of localtime() points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

```
struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);
```

The `localtime_r()` stores the data in a user-supplied struct.

In your example, it should be something similar to:

```
dayb4 = localtime_r(&t1, dayb4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calloc and overlapping structures, you could do the following:

```
struct tm now;
struct tm dayb4;
time_t t1 = time(NULL);

now = *localtime(&t1);
dayb4 = *localtime(&t1);

dayb4.tm_day -= 1;
mktime(&dayb4);
```